# Warning when the user Opens the written xls file using PHP Excel

Tags: php, phpexcel

> The file you're trying to open [fileName] is in different format than
>   specified by the file extension

I get that message whenever I open the xls files I've written using PHPExcel .. Is there anyway to get rid of that warning
,, the used code

```
<?php
require_once ('C:\wamp\www\phpexcel sample\Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php');
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("7asobate")->setDescription("PHPExcel tryout");
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setTitle("7asobate worksheet")->setCellValue('A1' , 'someValue1')
->setCellValue('A2' , 'someValue2');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel , 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('F:\myFile.xls');
?>
```

Comment: Yes, make sure that you use the correct extension for the file format that you're writing.... if you are using the `.xls` extension, then what Writer are you using to create these xls files?

Comment: Try using .xlsx instead of .xls

Comment: oh! I head that xlsx isn't compatible to Excel2007 so I made it xls .. it works just fine with Excel2007 .. thanks alot!

Comment: I don't know where you heard that, but the xlsx (OfficeOpenXML) format was created for Excel 2007